# How can this input result in an output of '**4 *2'?

Tags: c

How can this input result in an output of `**4   *2`? I don't understand.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 2; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("*");
    printf("%d ", i+j);
}
```

Comment: Try putting braces on the inner for loop - it'll make more sense ;)

Comment: What don't you understand? It is very clear

Comment: how can the output be **4 *2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Value of `i` is 2 for the first time. So,

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf(“*”);
```

prints 2 `*`s. When j becomes 2 loop breaks and

```
printf(“%d “, i+j);
```

prints `4`.

For next iteration of `for (i = 2; i > 0; i--)`, `i` is now  `1`.

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf(“*”);
```

prints 1 `*`. When j becomes 1 loop breaks and

```
printf(“%d “, i+j);
```

prints `2`.

Hence `**4*2`. And please indent your code for however trivial programs you write or you will keep getting confused.

Comment: Alright thanks Kunal, Also how would the addition result in 4? shouldn't it be 3 because i would be 2 and j would add twice once with a value of 0 and then with a value of 1. So 2+1+0 = 3 ? :/

Comment: `printf(“%d “, i+j);` is not inside the `for` loop. Without any braces around `for` only the next immediate statement is considered a part of `for` block. When the inner loop breaks, it breaks because `j=2` therefore it prints `i(2)+j(2)` = `4`.

Comment: When J breaks out of the first loop, it is 2.  i+j (2+2) == 4;  Step through it and you will see for yourself.

Comment: @JOJOMASTER I have edited your code. It may make more sense to you now.

Answer (score 1):

1. `i=2` and `j=0`
   `while j <2` =>> 2 times * by printf(“*”);
   `j=2` (cuz the `j++` (2 times))
2. `printf(“%d “, i+j);` 2+2
   then the output at this moment is ****4**
3. `i=1` and `j=0` (restart j)
   `while j<1` =>> 1 time * by printf(“*”);
   `j=1` (cuz the `j++` (1 time))
4. `printf(“%d “, i+j);` 1+1
   then the output at this moment is ****4 *2**

Answer (score 1):

Modified code for clarity:

```
int i, j;

    for (i = 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    printf("*");
                }
                printf(“"%d ", i+j);
    }
```

1.Upper `for` start by setting i=2

2.Inner loop start by setting j=0

3.print `*`

**Output: ***

4.increment j ( j=1 )

5.print `*`

**Output: ****

6.increment j ( j=2 )

7.Inner for loop finished

1. print ( i+j =4)

**Output:**4**

1. Decrement i. Now i = 1
2. Inner loop start by setting j=0
3. print `*`

**Output: **4 ***

1. increment j ( j=1 )

Inner loop finished

1. print ( i+j ) = 2

**output: **4 *2**

1. decrement i (now i= 0 )

Outer loop actioned

**Final output = **4 *2**

Comment: but the code says that j<i so how would j=2

Comment: @JOJOMASTER because in the last iteration j will be incremented so that j=2 and then `for` will check condition j<i and fail. so inner `for` won't be executed again, But j is still 2